# My command button is upside down

Tags: vba, excel, button, excel-2010

[image: Upside Down Button]

This is the image of my upside down button. It is supposed to say "Update Sheet"
I was just doing usual programming in Excel VBA and I went back to my workbook and found this. I have no idea why and how... I am very confused. But it works perfectly. I did some research online to at least get an idea of how this can ever happen; I couldn't find anything. apparently no one ever has had this problem.

Here are the button properties.

[image: Button Properties]

Comment: `Control + Alt + Down Arrow` ;)

Comment: Maybe your font has been replaced with an upside down font?  If you use `Arial Balck` in a worksheet cell, is it upside down?

Comment: You could either open the image in **Paint** and flip it, or else turn your monitor upside down.

Comment: No, in a worksheet cell, it's not upside down.